# Difference between MyClass.prototype = new Object() and MyClass.prototype = Object

Tags: javascript, inheritance

could anyone please tell me, where in Javascript the difference between

```
MyClass.prototype = new Object(); //or ... = {}
```

and

```
MyClass.prototype = Object;
```

is? And if there is no difference in the result, which one is the best-practise-way-to-go?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reason to use the 'new' keyword here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)

Comment: @Bergi this question is more than 4 years old. The one you linked to is 2 years old...

Comment: The 1.5-year old answer is still valid, and this question is still found via search and links. It should point to other helpful answers…

Comment: possible duplicate of [new MyObject(); vs new MyObject;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first two examples are completely equivalent:

```
MyClass.prototype = new Object(); // empty object
MyClass.prototype = {}; // empty object
```

Your third example is not valid, since you are assigning to the `MyClass.prototype` a reference to the [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object) constructor, and it's a function, not a new object.

I personally prefer the second, the object [literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Literals) or [initialiser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_Object_Initializers) syntax:

```
MyClass.prototype = {prop1: 'value', prop2: 'value2'};
//...
MyClass.prototype.foo = 'bar';
MyClass.prototype.method1: function () {/**/};
```

**Edit:** In response to your comment, an empty object literal `{ }` essentially equivalent to `new Object()` because of this:

> The production ObjectLiteral : { } is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Create a new object as if by the expression new Object().
> 2. Return Result(1).

For more details check the 11.1.5 section (Object Initialiser) of the [ECMAScript Language Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) (pdf).

**Edit:** The third example won't produce any errors, but is not good at all, for example you can easily clobber the Object constructor function if you extend afterward the MyClass.prototype:

```
MyClass.prototype = Object;
MyClass.prototype.foo = 'bar';

Object.foo === MyClass.prototype.foo; // true
```

Comment: Hmhm, so if both examples don't produce errors of any kind and essentially do the same (as it actually is), it is just the laxity of the browser's javascript engine that allows the second example to work?

Comment: No, I know that {} == new Object(). What I meant by "second example" was ...prototype = Object;

Answer (score 2):

It depends on `Object`.  If it is a function you want to use the `new Object()` method.  If it is a "virtual class" (defined using `Object = {someProperty: someValue}`) then you use the second method.

Some more pointers in [this page](http://phrogz.net/JS/Classes/OOPinJS2.html) on prototype inheritance in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

> MyClass.prototype.method1: function ()
>   {/**/};

Correction to the above: it should be

```
MyClass.prototype.method1 = function () {/**/};
```

(Note the equals sign after 'method1').

The colon is used only when the method definition is itself within an object definition, like:

```
var myObject = {myVar1: 10, myMethod1: function() { /* */};
```