# How To call a Function from an Object Method that call parent properties

Tags: javascript

```
        function myFunc() {
        omaps: function tes() {
            return this.parent.x + this.parent.y;
        }
    }

    var myobj = {
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
        z: myFunc()
    }

    window.alert(myobj.z);
```

**return undefined**

```
        function myFunc() {
        omaps: function tes() {
            return myobj.x + myobj.y;
        }
    }

    var myobj = {
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
        z: myFunc()
    }

    window.alert(myobj.z);
```

**return undefined**

```
        var myobj = {
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
        z: {
            omaps: function() {
                return myobj.x + myobj.y;
            }
        }
    }

    window.alert(myobj.z);
```

**return [object, Object]**

From the snippets above I get a return with undefined or [object, Object] instead of value 3.

How do I return the value I expected? Do I do it right or wrong?

Comment: That code is not syntactically correct, you should not be able to get `(Object, object)`. Please check that you have pasted it correctly first. Also - note that `method1:` here is not a method - if anything, it would be a label (if the rest was syntactically correct).

Comment: Aren't you getting syntax error ?

Comment: I would expect z:myFunc().method1()

Comment: @mplungjan—I'd expect *undefined* (if the syntax error is fixed), since *myFunc* doesn't have a return statement.

Comment: Method1 does hjowever have a return value

Comment: *Method1* is a label followed by a function declaration without a name (hence the syntax error). Giving the function a name fixes that, but that function isn't called, so *myFunc* returns *undefined*.

Comment: edit the question and sorry changing method1 to omaps.

Comment: Even though there's an answer, you might still find it hard to understand. No offense, but you need to learn fundamentals first.

Comment: @Leo actually I did, maybe did'nt good enough, anyway I use the above code by modifying from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4892252/163812. So in my understanding it should not get any wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first two examples you get *undefined* because the value assigned to *myobj.z* is the result of calling *myFunc*.

That function doesn't have a return statement, so it returns *undefined* and that is the value assigned to *myobj.z*.

In the third example, you are assigning an object to *myobj.z*, so you see the result of calling the *toString* method inherited from *Object* constructor (i.e. the one on [*Object.prototype*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2)), which returns `'[object Object]'`.

Probably what you want to do is:

```
// Function assumes *this* will be set in the call
function myFunc() {
    return this.x + this.y;
}

var myobj = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: myFunc  // note assignment, no ()
}

window.alert(myobj.z());  // Note *this* must be set in the call and z must be called
```

You could also use a [*getter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) (supported in modern browsers):

```
var myobj = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    get z(){
      return this.x + this.y;
    }
}

window.alert(myobj.z)  // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign the function to `myobj.z` and use `this.x` and `this.y` to get the properties and getting the value by calling `myobj.z()` like this

```
function myFunc() {
        return this.x + this.y;
    }

    var myobj = {
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
        z: myFunc
    }

    window.alert(myobj.z());
```

another way is to pass the the object in the function to get the properties and assign return value to `myobj.z` like this

```
function myFunc(obj) {
        return obj.x + obj.y;
    }

    var myobj = {
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
        z: myFunc(myobj)
    }

    window.alert(myobj.z);
```

Comment: Have you tried the second method? You might find you get a type error since *myobj* has a value of *undefined* when *myFunc* is called.