# How do you call a previously defined function in a JS object definition?

Tags: javascript

If you try running this JS snippet,

```
module.exports = {
  add: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
  subtract: function(a, b) { return add(a, -b); }
}
```

you'll get an error, saying that `add` is undefined. The same applies here:

```
module.exports = {
  add: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
  sums: {
    two_and_three: add(2,3);
  }
}
```

What is the best way to call a previously mentioned function in this way?

Comment: `add` isn't defined in that scope. It's defined as a key in the object, but keys are not variable definitions.

Comment: @4castle Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `this` as indicated below:

```
module.exports = {
  add: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
  subtract: function(a, b) { return this.add(a, -b); }
}
```

For your second use case you need something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  add: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
  sums: {
    two_and_three: function() { return module.exports.add(2,3); }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Understanding various [JS function invocation patterns](http://doctrina.org/Javascript-Function-Invocation-Patterns.html) would help here:

How the function is called, decides the function's context, which is accessible using `'this'` keyword inside the function.

Now coming to your code:

```
module.exports = {
  add: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
  subtract: function(a, b) { return add(a, -b); }
}
```

We would call the subtract function in the following way:

```
module.exports.subtract(1, 3);
```

Method invocation pattern is used here. Which means that `this` inside the subtract function would refer to substract's parent object (`module.exports`), which also contains the `add` function. Hence, the `add` function can be accessed using `this.add` inside the subtract function, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  add: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
  subtract: function(a, b) { return this.add(a, -b); }
}
```

For the second case, you can use [wdosanjos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711582/wdosanjos)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450384/how-do-you-call-a-previously-defined-function-in-a-js-object-definition/41450456#41450456), if having `sums.two_and_three` as a function works for you, or if you need sums as the results, this can be done:

```
module.exports = {
    add: function(a, b) { return a + b; }
};

module.exports.sums = {
    two_and_three: module.exports.add(2,3),
    three_and_four: module.exports.add(3,4)
};
```

Or, there are some other ways suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892221/i-need-to-call-a-parent-property-from-child-object-in-an-object-literal), for accessing parent object's siblings/properties.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

```
module.exports = {
   add: function(a, b) { return a + b; },

   subtract: function(a, b) { return this.add(a, -b); }
 }
```