# Typescript: Accessing a parent property from child object in a constant

Tags: typescript

In this Typescript/Javascript code:

```
var v= {
  x: 1,
  y: {
    z: v.x,
  }
}

const c = {
  x: 1,
  y: {
    z: c.x,
  }
}
```

v is ok because `var` is JavaScript and it doesn't complain, but when assigning z in c there is an error because of the use of z before its declaration.

My question: is there a way to get it?
(I know I could declare another x out of c and assign its value inside, but I mean something more direct)

Comment: Not sure that either of those will work at all. I don't think you can reference an object in it's own initializer, with either `var` or `const`. It's unfortunate that typescript doesn't complain about the first case, since both of these will produce runtime error: `cannot read property 'x' of undefined`

Comment: In the first case it does not complain (I'm in Visual Code)

Answer (score 1):

Both examples will throw an error as `v` does not yet exist at the time when the expression `v.x` is evaluated:

**var**

```js
var v= {
  x: 1,
  y: {
    z: v.x, // TypeError
  }
}
```

**const**

```js
const c = {
  x: 1,
  y: {
    z: c.x, // TypeError
  }
}
```

You'll have to resort to adding the object *after* `c` is initialized:

```js
const c = {
  x: 1
}

c.y = { z: c.x };

console.log(c.y.z);
```

Comment: The first code (var v...) does NOT throw an error, I've tested it in Visual Code. See first answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892221/i-need-to-call-a-parent-property-from-child-object-in-an-object-literal

What you propose for c is just what I proposed like a solution. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to make `z` lazy:

```js
var v = {
   x: 1,
   y: {
      z: () => v.x,
   }
}

const c = {
   x: 1,
   y: {
      z: () => c.x,
   }
}

console.log(v.y.z());
console.log(c.y.z());
```

Comment: But the question was NOT about v, but about c

Comment: @user3372174 should still work with `c`. updated answer.