# Parentheses after "new <function>" optional?

Tags: javascript, initialization, new-operator

I have run the following pair of code snippets in Chrome console, with the same results:

```
test = new function(){
  var a = 1;
  var b = 2;
  var c = 3;
  this.debugBase = function(){console.log('' + a + b + c)};
};
test
debugBase: function (){console.log('' + a + b + c)}
__proto__: Object
```

Versus:

```
test2 = new (function(){
  var a = 1;
  var b = 2;
  var c = 3;
  this.debugBase = function(){console.log('' + a + b + c)};
})();
test2
debugBase: function (){console.log('' + a + b + c)}
__proto__: Object
```

Am I missing something?  Is there any significance to the parentheses after the function?  If not, why do people put them there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A similar questions was asked here: [new MyClass() vs. new MyClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myclass-vs-new-myclass). The complete and accepted answer by Daniel Vassallo:

> Quoting [David Flanagan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myclass-vs-new-myclass)<sup>1</sup>:
>
> > As a special case, for the `new` operator only, JavaScript simplifies the grammar by allowing the parenthesis to be omitted if there are no arguments in the function call. Here are some examples using the `new` operator:
> >
> > ```
> > o = new Object;  // Optional parenthesis omitted here
> > d = new Date();
> > ```
>
> ---
>
> Personally, I always use the parenthesis, even when the constructor takes no arguments.
>
> In addition, [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) may hurt your feelings if you omit the parenthesis. It reports `Missing '()' invoking a constructor`, and there doesn't seem to be an option for the tool to tolerate parenthesis omission.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1</sup> David Flanagan: [JavaScript the Definitive Guide: 4th Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000486) (page 75)

Answer (score 3):

Because you can pass parameters like this, eg.

```
var x = new String(5); // '5'
```

Other than that, it is a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

putting the parantheses actually runs the function.  Without them, the function is just defined.

**EDIT:**  I didn't notice the "new" keyword you used.  Your function is called in either case.  You don't generally need the new keyword here though.  In the example you've given, they are essentially the same, the parentheses at the end are redundant.

See this jsfiddle for what I mean ( http://jsfiddle.net/Gs2jH/ ).

If you run it, you'll see that only the 2nd item is called.

Comment: But looking at the output of the console, the object is instantiated regardless.