# difference between calling function with braces and without bracs

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if there any difference between `new FunctionOne` and `new FunctionOne()` where FunctionOne is defined as

```
 function FunctionOne(){
   /// this function has no arguments
   ///some code 
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [new MyObject(); vs new MyObject;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject)

Comment: I would imagine the parentheses allow you to pass arguments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parentheses after "new <function>" optional?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439290/parentheses-after-new-function-optional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference but to pass arguments when operator `()` is used. Other than that, both can be used to having the same effect. For example.

```
( new Date() ).getTime();
```

is the same as

```
( new Date ).getTime();
```