# "new Dog" or "new Dog()"

Tags: javascript

What is difference if any between "instantiating" the JavaScript "class" with or without using parenthesis?

```
function Animal(name) {
     this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
     console.log(this.name);
};

function Dog(name) {
     Animal.call(this, name);
}

Dog.prototype = new Animal(null);
Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
     console.log("Woof!");
};

var d = new Dog
```

or

```
var d = new Dog()
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439290/parentheses-after-new-function-optional)

There is no difference between them, as long as the constructor function takes no parameter. That is: calling new Dog (with no parentheses) is like calling new Dog() with no arguments.