# Difference between new object with or without execute brackets

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [new MyClass(); vs new MyClass;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myclass-vs-new-myclass)

Please see comments below

When creating a new instance of an object, what is the difference between **A** and **B** below

**A**, using brackets

```
var foo = new Bar();
```

**B** without brackets

```
var foo = new Bar;
```

I am using backbone.js where many examples do not use brackets. Also, what is the correct terminology to call the `()`'s? Execute?

Comment: Remarkably similar duplicate, and the answer you linked to has a much more complete answer. There should be some way of aliasing question names so that one question may have multiple names to increase the chances of a search hitting the questions.