# In Javascript, Difference Between `new MyFunction()` and `new MyFunction`

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [new MyClass(); vs new MyClass;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myclass-vs-new-myclass)

Given a Javascript function like...

```
var MyFunction = function() {
    /*  Any arbitrary Javascript */
}
```

Are the two following lines of Javascript semantically *exactly* the same?

```
func_obj = new MyFunction()
```

...

```
func_obj = new MyFunction
```

i.e., is the `()` just syntactical sugar?

Thanks.

Comment: My question is exactly answered by that Q&A; so, yeah, its a dupe. Thanks!