# JS new Object VS new Object()

Tags: javascript, instantiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [new MyObject(); vs new MyObject;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject)

What is the difference between

```
new Object
```

and

```
new Object()
```

Is there a **reason** to ever leave the parenthesis out or is that just *something people do sometimes*?

Comment: They're the same, `new Object` is just slightly shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference

Comment: Why all the dots????  See the little tricks you pick up hanging around here too much....  ;)

Comment: At least `JSLint` complaing about `new Object`.

Comment: @OliverWeiler: JSLint complains about all sorts of silly things.