# What is the difference between new Object and new Object() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [new MyObject(); vs new MyObject;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject)

In some articles I seen following statement to create new object in JavaScript:

```
var myObject = new Object;
```

and at some sites:

```
var myObject = new Object();
```

In there is any difference between two statements or one is just shorthand?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no difference. Parentheses are optional when using a function as a constructor (i.e. with the `new` operator) and no parameters. When not using the `new` operator, parentheses are always required when calling a function.

As noted in another answer, it's generally preferable to use an object literal instead. It has the following advantages over using the `Object` constructor:

- Allows concise initialization of properties (e.g. `var foo = { bar: "cheese" };`)
- Shorter
- Possibly faster
- Unaffected in the (unlikely) event of the `Object` function being overwritten.

Comment: +1 Very good answer, didn't know about the last thing (Unaffected in the (unlikely) event of the Object function being overwritten.).

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer - don't use that syntax. The preferred way for creating objects in JavaScript is to use the following syntax:

```
var myObject = {}; // creates an empty object
```

Comment: that is a good answer, but an explanation of why would make it great.

Comment: It isn't a good answer as it doesn't address the question. It should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. It just happens that in this special case, you can omit the `()`.

So
    new Object()

and

```
new Object
```

are equivalent.

BTW, there is also no difference in using `new Object()` over `{}`. Use whatever you prefer.