# Javascript use of "new"

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [new MyObject(); vs new MyObject;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject)
>   [What is the difference between new Object and new Object() in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360243/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-new-object-in-javascript)

What is the difference between,

```
new ClassName;
```

and

```
new ClassName();
```

?

Do they have the same result?

Comment: The downvote seems harsh, what's the logic there?

Comment: I downvoted for no research effort, u mad? :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference. Use the latter if you want to pass arguments.

The parentheses are also required in chaining:

```
new ClassName().method();
```

Creates `new ClassName` object and calls `method` on it.

```
new ClassName.method();
```

Tries to construct `ClassName.method` object

See [the relevant section in spec](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.2)

Comment: FWIW, the [5th edition spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2) has been out for a couple of years now.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit, didn't wanna make separate answer

Comment: @Esailija: +1 on the edit, good to make that point.