# backbone.js collection reset parentheses

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

The question title might be a misleading and this might be more of a generic javascript question, but anyways, I noticed in the example given in http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset

```
var accounts = new Backbone.Collection;
accounts.reset(<%= @accounts.to_json %>);
```

that new Backbone.Collection is called without parentheses at the end.

```
//Is there any difference?
var accounts = new Backbone.Collection;
var accounts = new Backbone.Collection();
```

What's the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [new MyObject(); vs new MyObject;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject)

Comment: For quick reference, there is no difference : new Backbone.Collection === new Backbone.Collection();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by nikoshr, this is a duplicate of [Can we omit parentheses when creating an object using the "new" operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject)

The answer, as given there, is:

#### no, there is no difference.

If no arguments are required for your constructor, it is simply a shorthand convenience in Javascript to not have to specify that. However, some consider it bad practice, including Douglas Crockford.