# Why would you invoke new Date without parentheses?

Tags: javascript, datetime, constructor

I have just seen this snippet while accidentally opening dev tools in Gmail:

```
var GM_TIMING_END_CHUNK1=(new Date).getTime();
```

I would usually expect something like this, as it's rather uncommon to invoke a constructor without parentheses (at least I have never seen it until now):

```
var GM_TIMING_END_CHUNK1=new Date().getTime();
```

or

```
var GM_TIMING_END_CHUNK1=Date.now(); //newer browsers
```

Is there any advantage in doing so, any difference in behavior? It's the exact same amount of characters needed, so brevity won't be a reason.

Comment: How about `var d = new Date;` if you want the date as an object? That saves two characters. Perhaps this was done to ease familiarity for C++ programmers, where default constructors aren't called with parentheses do to the so-called "most vexing parse" (historically, at least; I don't know if that behavior has changed in recent versions of the C++ standard).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can invoke constructors in JS w/o the parenthesis if no arguments are to be passed, the effect is the same.

`new Date()` vs `new Date` the same.

However, it makes a difference when you want to call a method on the resulting object:

`new Date().getTime()` works but `new Date.getTime()` would not because in the latter case the interpreter assumes `getTime` is a method of the Date *type* which isn't the case, `getTime` is an instance method.  To overcome this you can wrap parenthesis around the constructor call to tell the interpreter that it is an expression:

`(new Date).getTime()`

This way first the expression is evaluated and `getTime` is called on the result which is an instance of Date.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the existing comments about optional parentheses -- i.e. `new Date() <==> new Date` -- note also that `Date.now` is a static method. That is, no `Date` object is ever instantiated. The method is a property of the `Date` constructor itself. In this way, it is different than the other two examples.

As a matter of style, I prefer including all optional parens for consistency and clarity:

```
(new Date()).getTime()
```

Answer (score 2):

When a function is used as an object constructor and no arguments are being passed, the parentheses are optional.  `d = new Date;` means the same thing as `d = new Date();`.

Comment: Ok, this seems reasonable, thanks. Is there any reason for this practice being so uncommon, then?

Comment: @m90 I'd say it's uncomon because it hurts readability and only works when you don't want to pass in any arguments.

Comment: It's uncommon because it confuses people such as yourself. :)  In languages such as Ruby you can call methods or functions without parentheses in other contexts, not just construction, but in Javascript it's such a special case that it probably doesn't even occur to most programmers to try it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in both statements, parenthesis are optional, So usually programmers drop it.

In your second example:

```
new Date().getTime();
```

one of good practice programmers follow to wrap object in parenthesis before calling function or property. so it will be:

```
(new Date()).getTime();
```

as discussed above object parenthesis are optional. So shorter cleaner code is:

```
(new Date).getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this answer:
[Can we omit parentheses when creating an object using the "new" operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject)

Basicly `new Date` is equivilent to writing `new Date()` though you might prefer to use `new Date()` for consistency, since functions and constructors are so similar in JavaScript and the parentheses-less syntax is definitely illegal for function invocation.