# Operator precedence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I am reading operator precedence on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). It shows "===" has higher precedence than "||" operator. If it is true, then "a === doesThisHappen()" will run first. But why I did not get console.log('This happens!')?

```
var a;

a = 1;

function doesThisHappen() {

    console.log('This happens!');

    return 0;
}

if (a || a === doesThisHappen()) {
    console.log('Something is there.');
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence This is the page for operator precedence

Comment: you should see the log

Comment: @RonaldoMessi: *One* of them, yes; not the other.

Comment: This question is sadly ***the*** top search engine hit for `site:stackoverflow.com operator precedence JavaScript` (for a particular search engine at a particular time). A slightly more relevant hit is *[What is the correct JavaScript operator precedence table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158960/what-is-the-correct-javascript-operator-precedence-table)*. Yes, Stack Overflow shouldn't be used this way, but still the search engine hits ought to be much more relevant.

Comment: Though following the link that happens to be in the question leads the right place.

Answer (score 3):

Order of evaluation and operator precedence are orthogonal concepts. In `a || b` the left side `a` is evaluated first no matter what the right side `b` contains. More over, if the left side evaluates to true the right side is not evaluated.

Comment: E.g., *precedence* doesn't come into play here. *Associativity* does.