# Is there a difference between new Person and new Person()?

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference/benefit between these two ways of instantiating an object?

Example:

```
var Person = (function () {
 function Person() {
 }
 return Person;
})();

var p = new Person();
p.Name = "Greg";
window.console.log(p.Name);

var x = new Person;
x.Name = "Pete";
window.console.log(x.Name);
```

Comment: Not really. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject for explanation.

Comment: therefore it's a duplicate

Comment: If a constructor takes no arguments, the empty parenthesized argument list is optional when the constructor is invoked with `new`.

Comment: thanks @Pointy you always make your explanations so simple +1