# JavaScript’s Date.now() returning 0 (zero)

Tags: javascript, date, mocha.js

I basically copy-pasted the [Mocha.js Base reporter](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/reporters/base.js) to build a custom reporter.
Now for some reason, inside the `on "end"` callback, `Date.now()` returns `0`,
while `new Date()` returns a date for `Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)`.

And I really don’t get it. This language is driving me nuts.
Hope someone knows what’s going on here.

[image]

Comment: I see new Date; over there, you sure you did new Date()?

Comment: What do you see in the console if you just type `Date.now`? It should be `function now() { [native code] }`. If it isn't, then something has overridden it

Comment: @Steve doesn't matter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject

Comment: @Phil nice! `function now() { return target.clock.now; }` looks like something changed the function. `clock` sounds like it may be coming from sinon.js. I’ll look into it. Thanks man!

Comment: you might want to add some CSP to this page, with the rule "don't override existing prototypes" at the very least. That should even tell you what's doing the redefining.

Comment: It’s sinon.js’ fake timer: https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/blob/5ea0c84c2d95187da191039fe3923d697a4c09e9/lib/sinon/util/fake_timers.js#L115-L117

Answer (score 1):

You might be using sinon's fake timer somewhere in another test

```
clock = sinon.useFakeTimers()
```

but forgetting to restore it after the tests finished running:

```
clock.restore()
```