# new XMLHttpRequest() vs new XMLHttpRequest - What is the difference?

Tags: javascript

While experimenting different ways of achieving the same result I stumbled on this scenario. I tried both XMLHttpRequest and Image without the parenthesis and the result appears to be the same, as the provided example below shows.

```js
var Image1 = new Image(),
    Image2 = new Image,
    source = "data:image/png;base64,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";
Image1.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("Image1").appendChild(Image1);
};
Image2.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("Image2").appendChild(Image2);
};
Image1.src = source;
Image2.src = source;
```

```html
<div id="Image1"></div>
<div id="Image2"></div>
```

---

So what is the difference between using with and without parenthesis if both appear to achieve the same result?

Comment: No difference unless you want to pass arguments

Comment: Javascript syntactic sugar. Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no practical difference. Javascript, like many other languages, allows you to drop the empty parens when calling an empty constructor to initialize an object.