# JS - Which is correct, new Date or new Date()?

Tags: javascript, syntax

What's the correct syntax in JavaScript:

```
var x = new Date;
```

OR

```
var x = new Date();
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [new MyObject(); vs new MyObject;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct, just a matter of taste.

But usually it is preferred to use braces even though you don't pass any parameters, because these two snippets do not have the same evaluation:

Incorrect one

```
new Date.valueOf(); // to work it should be (new Date).valueOf()
```

Correct one

```
new Date().valueOf();
```

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct. Parentheses are optional when the `new` operator is used and there are no arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct. 
You could also use the parameterized constructors.

E.G:-    `var d = new Date(1993, 6, 28, 14, 39, 7);`

```
    console.log(d.toString());     // prints Wed Jul 28 1993 14:39:07 GMT-0600 (PDT)
    console.log(d.toDateString()); // prints Wed Jul 28 1993
```

Comment: This post does **NOT** provide any answer to OP's problem!

Comment: @undone: I have edited the answer. I just wanted to emphasize on the parameterized constructors of Date object.
Thank you for pointing out the mistakes.