# Uglify Is Minifying `new Obj();` Wrong

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am using gulp and gulp-uglify to minify my javascript code.

**Gulp**

```
var uglify= require('gulp-uglify');
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
    return gulp.src('./scripts/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

**Original javascript**

```
var Site = Site || {};
Site.Code = {
    obj: new ThirdPartyObject(),
    init: function() {
        obj.thirdPartyMethod();
    }
};
```

**Minified javascript**

```
var Site = Site || {};
Site.Code = {obj: new ThirdPartyObject,init: function() {
    obj.thirdPartyMethod()
}};
```

The minifier is removing the parentheses for `obj: new ThirdPartyObject` and therefore my code breaks when I make the call `obj.thirPartyMethod()`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you'd test your code *unminified* you'd find out that it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minifier is correct `new X()` and `new X` are equivalent.

Your code however, is not as correct. Here is the correct version:

```
var Site = Site || {};
Site.Code = {
    obj: new ThirdPartyObject(),
    init: function() {
        Site.Code.obj.thirdPartyMethod(); // <-- obj didn't exist
        // this.obj.thirdPartyMethod(); <-- also works, because this will be Site.Code when invoking Site.Code.init()
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Uglify is correct here. See [new MyObject(); vs new MyObject;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject) on StackOverflow.

`new ThirdPartyObject;` is a correct statement as a special case of `new` when applied to a constructor that takes no arguments.

Your call `obj.thirdPartyMethod()` is likely failing for other reasons. Are you sure `obj` is correctly resolved at the scope in which the `init` function is called? Do you need a `this.`, or a reference to `Site.Code`?