# Difference between `new function(){this.x=1}` and `{x:1}`

Tags: javascript

```
var Foo = new function(){
    this.A = 1;
    this.B = 2;
};
var Bar = {
    A: 1,
    B: 2
};
typeof Foo === "object"
typeof Bar === "object"
```

What's the difference between the two?

I only found their `__proto__` objects to be different:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you found the difference. They have different prototypes.

Comment: There's not much practical difference other than the difference in prototype, but since the prototype has nothing on it for the first object, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: you can sort of see Foo as a class, but Bar is an object

Comment: @Ji_in_coding no, Foo is just an object. The anonymous constructor is **called** by the `new` operator.

Answer (score 0):

OK:

```
var Foo = new function(){
    this.A = 1;
    this.B = 2;
};
```

We've got `var Foo = new` *a function* — which means that the runtime will invoke that function with `this` set to a newly-constructed object whose internal prototype link will be set to the value of the "prototype" property of that function. Because that's just an anonymous function instantiated right there in the initialization, its "prototype" property is just a plain empty object, so it really doesn't do anything. The constructor function does initialize two properties of the new object, and that new object is the returned value from the `new` expression. Thus, `Foo` is assigned a reference to that constructed object, and the object has a couple of assigned properties. It also has a prototype chain that includes the empty object from the anonymous constructor function, and then after that the prototype inherited from the Object constructor.

In this:

```
var Bar = {
    A: 1,
    B: 2
};
```

we have a variable (`Bar`) being set to the result of an object initializer expression. That always creates a plain object that inherits only from the Object prototype. The only way that this object is different from the `Foo` object is that the `Foo` object has an extra (empty) object in its prototype chain.

**So:**

- `Foo` will end up being a **plain object**, not a function.
- `Bar` will also be a plain object, more obviously not a function.
- `Foo` and `Bar` will be *similar* but not *identical* (well, two different objects are never identical, but I mean in terms of their particular characteristics) because `Foo` has that extra empty object in its prototype chain.

Answer (score -1):

The first one is a function constructor which outputs a function object (what is assigned to `Foo`), and the other is just a plain javascript object.

Comment: You missed the fact that the constructor is **called** via the `new` operator.

Comment: @Pointy i suppose he has subtly implied that by "function constructor", but being precise would be nice

Comment: @Ji_in_coding Foo is just an object; it is not a function and it is not a constructor.

Comment: @Pointy, oh you are right, i just noticed there is a "new" before the function

Comment: @Pointy I'm sorry,  but it is a function constructor. Here is the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: `new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)`

Comment: No, it is not. The `new` operator causes that function to be **called**, and Foo is assigned the newly-constructed object.

Comment: We're saying the same thing. `new function(){}` is a function constructor. It outputs a function object.

Comment: @justinledouxweb no, we are **not** saying the same thing. `new` followed by a function causes that function to be **immediately called** and the result is the new object created. There is a function involved, but that function is called and the value of Foo will be a plain object. Try it yourself in your browser console!

Comment: Sure, a new function object. Read the first sentence on the link I posted. It is exactly saying what we are saying.

Comment: Sure in both cases `typeof Foo` and `typeof Bar` is equal to `object`, but the difference is one is a function object (an object that extends the native function object, and the other is an object initializer. They both have different prototypes because they extend a different native object.

Comment: @justinledouxweb no no no no no no no no no.  Foo is **absolutely not** a Function instance. It's a plain object. The `new` before that anonymous function means that the anonymous function is **called as a constructor**, and Foo is set to the **result** of that call. The result is a plain non-function object.

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript all functions are objects. And in your case Foo and Bar are the same, but you can construct the first.

On the same token, I would say that the key insight with constructor functions in this case is that if we have:

```
function myFoo (){
    this.A = 1;
    this.B = 2;
};
```

then

```
var Foo1 = new myFoo();
```

the *this* context is Foo.

```
var Foo2 = myFoo();
```

the *this* is bound to the current context, the window object in this case (meaning you actually have window.A = 1).

See the MDN documentation for a more extensive description.

[Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

[Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

[new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but in this case neither Foo nor Bar are functions. They are both objects.

Comment: new function() {}, not new function() {} ().

Comment: @djechlin the `()` is optional!

Comment: @Pointy I learned that while researching this...  I would consider pointing that out a pretty important part of the answer. You should submit an answer, btw.

Comment: @djechlin this question got pretty crazy :)

Comment: @Pointy it's a pretty good question though. I'm surprised it's only had my upvote so far. Or find a good dupe.

Answer (score -1):

First note [it's irrelevant that you omitted the parentheses when calling your anonymous function with `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject). JSLint will yell at you because it's confusing to do this, but that's what's going on.

I'm pretty sure the internal prototype is the only difference. It may be easier to write this out as it's normally used.

```
var Car = function() {
    this.seats = 4;
};

var car1 = new Car();
var car2 = {
    seats: 4
};
```

Reading this it's clear to me that `car1` is an object whose internal prototype is `Car` - which in your case is an anonymous function not directly held by a variable - and `car2` is an object whose internal prototype is Object.

Comment: The prototype of `car1` will be the value of the "prototype" property of `Car`, not `Car` itself.