# Using webpack worker-loader with nuxt.js

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use Web Worker within the [nuxt.js framework](https://nuxtjs.org/) but keep getting a reference error. `ReferenceError: Worker is not defined`.

I have installed [worker-loader 1.1.1](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader) via npm and added the following rule to my `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  build: {
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
      // Web Worker support
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.worker\.js$/,
        use: { loader: 'worker-loader' },
        exclude: /(node_modules)/
      })
    }
  }
}
```

If I create a build via `nuxt build` it looks like the web worker file is created.

```
Asset                           Size                      
2a202b9d805e69831a05.worker.js  632 bytes          [emitted]
```

I import it inside a vuex module, like so:

```js
import Worker from '~/assets/js/shared/Loader.worker.js'

console.log(Worker)
const worker = new Worker // <- this line fails!
```

In the console I get what looks like a function to create the worker:

```js
ƒ () {
  return new Worker(__webpack_require__.p + "345c16d02e75e9312f73.worker.js");
}
```

Inside the worker, I just have some dummy code to see if it actually works:

```js
const msg = 'world!'

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  console.log(event.data)
  self.postMessage({ hello: msg })
})

self.postMessage({ hello: 'from web worker' })
```

Comment: I've also tried to use workerize-loader but are getting a different error. I'm sure it has to do with my configuration but I still don't know what to do. https://github.com/developit/workerize-loader/issues/27

Comment: shouldn't it be `new Worker()`?

Comment: @lukas-reineke if you don't send arguments to a constructor in JS then the parentheses are optional. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3034952/205696
Anyway, I tried both (and many other things) and it all failed.

Comment: try  to import this way **import * as Worker from "worker-loader!~/assets/js/shared/Loader.worker.js'";** this type of import and and then create a instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's first get some things settled:

- workers are only available at client side -> no ssr

So either you need to use the [no ssr component](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-no-ssr#the-lt-no-ssr-gt-component), or need to set the the application to no [ssr](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#ssr)

With this knowledge, we will modify our `nuxt.config.js` as follows:

```
mode: 'spa',
build: {
  extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
    ...
    // Web Worker support
    if (isClient) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.worker\.js$/,
        use: { loader: 'worker-loader' },
        exclude: /(node_modules)/
      })
    }
  }
}
```

after `npm run build` and `npm run start` it should work like a charm.

I created a repo for you, it is a standard nuxt template with worker-loader utilized: [Github Repo](https://github.com/Greaka/standardNuxt)

Comment: Finally - Thanks @Greaka!
Only now, that I understand why, I got another issue. How do I build a normal SSR capable version of nuxt with a client-side only web worker? My main issue for not using `<no-ssr>` is that the web worker is used inside a vuex module, to do pre-fetching.

Comment: Seems that I can implement it as a plugin - but not sure how to use the plugin in vuex code...
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1607#issuecomment-328489139

Comment: OK. It works in a plugin with ssr set to false. `{ src: '~/plugins/load-ww', ssr: false }` but the vuex files a run before the plugins so I can not make the web worker accessible from to a store file via `Vue.use()`.

Comment: With the latest source for nuxt, dev modes works fine with worker-loader. I just did a git clone and it works

Comment: I just rushed here because it struck my mind. Webworkers do get registered in Dev mode, i will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: You cannot use workers server side. if you just want to prefatch data, use [asyncdata](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/async-data-components#async-data-in-components-). Another option is to write [your own loader](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/) which you call if `!isClient`. The loader could for example change the path to e.g. instead of `*.worker.js` -> `*.js`. Downside: you have to write the same code multiple times. workaround: import the non worker script in the worker and just call the functions. the webworker will be just a wrapper for offloading it in the client.

Comment: I figured out to put the web worker instantiation in a `ssr: false` plugin and inject it into nuxt. Then I can use it in a `if (process.browser) ` guard in vuex actions. I'm preloading thousands of SVG and images for a viewer. IMHO it's better to use browser caching than anything else for that. I just need vuex to keep track of what I preload. It largely depends on the user navigation in the app, what prefetch strategy I use.

Comment: I played around with it and ended with an example PR: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/3044

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter thanks for demo, but it seems it doesn't work in hot reloading mode in nuxt-edge

Comment: @husayt Looks like you answered the question yourself in https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/3480#issuecomment-404150387

Comment: Indeed @dotnetCarpenter. Thanks for all the changes

Answer (score 2):

With worker-loader, there's [the fallback option](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader#fallback) but personally (and this is what I'm doing) I would keep only the communication code inside the immediate worker file, importing a second file with the actual workload. This way the second file can also be imported serverside.
Most likely in a forked thread/threadpool, unless you are in a FaaS context and your main thread has literally nothing else to do.

Also, did you have to use the following in `nuxt.config.js`? For me, without it, it was "window is undefined". (in the browser, when trying to instantiate worker)

```js
extend(config, ctx) {
    /*
    ** Required for HotModuleReloading to work with worker-loader
    */
    config.output.globalObject = 'this'
}
```

Comment: This was due to a comment by @husayt https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/3480#issuecomment-404150387. However in 1.4.0, it doesn't seem to work anyway. So I removed it and in nuxt page I get the reference through `async fetch({app}) {
    app.$worker` and in a store I can still use `this.$worker`. Sorry for the bad formatting, but SO peeps think it's great(!) - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216927/code-in-comments-does-not-work