# It has a way to use shared-workers with NuxtJS v.2.14.12?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, shared-worker

I've a NuxtJS application and I'm trying to share a websocket connection throught the open tabs. Researching for this, I have found a way using shared-workers but I dont found this at Nuxt / Nuxt PWA documentation. I only found way to create custom workers in Nuxt PWA module with workbox.

Comment: https://github.com/Kong/swrv

Comment: Does it help you in any way? I'll do more research on this specifically regarding PWA

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs I'll read and study this to see if its applies, I'll return here for updates, thank you.

Comment: OK, great, I'll do the research myself meanwhile

Comment: Hey @AifosSiPrahs, I've been solved this "issue" using a Worker-Loader. I'll anwser the question with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been solved this problem using a Worker-Loader in my project. With this, I can configure worker files, incluse type of worker (sharedworker in this case) and import like a javascript module inside my component file.

This helps me how to configure: [Using webpack worker-loader with nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144599/using-webpack-worker-loader-with-nuxt-js)