# Correct way of exporting classes in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

For a longer time I've asked myself if there's a real difference between these 3 methods of exporting an entire class in Node.js. Is there a "correct" way or any differences within the different kind of methods?

Let's say we have this example class:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'foobar';
    }

    bar() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
```

What would be the correct way of exporting this class in a Node.js environment?

```
module.exports = new Foo();
```

or

```
module.exports = new Foo;
```

or

```
module.exports = Foo;
```

Thanks a lot for any answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports = new Foo();
```

This would mean you are exporting an instance of the class and not the class itself.

As in, when you `require('./Foo')`, you get the object and not the class.

Similar case with the

```
module.exports = new Foo;
```

Although JSLint [would complain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3034952/4382683) if you omit parenthesis.

But,

```
module.exports = Foo;
```

would mean you are exporting the class, you'd be able to use it as such:

```
const Foo = require('./Foo');
const foo = new Foo();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a perfect explanation to my question!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Faizuddin Mohammed's answer you can also make es6 exports this way (which i always do):

```
export class MyClass { ....
```

this can be imported like this:

```
import { MyClass } from "...."
```

or using default exports:

```
class MyClass {}
export default MyClass
```

which would be imported this way:

```
import MyClass from "..."
```

Greetings and happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports = Foo`
is the right choice see the reference [here](https://rishabh.io/recipes/how-to-export-a-class-from-module-nodejs6.html)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a right way to export classes and the method depends on your needs (do you need to export the class itself or an instance of the class).

The most common way is to use (this exports the class itself)

```
module.exports = Foo;
```

or in ES6

```
export default Foo
```

and importing would be like

```
const Foo = require('./Foo');
const foo = new Foo();
```

or in ES6

```
import Foo from './Foo'
const foo = new Foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a "correct" way to export a class, since different exports are suitable for different purposes.

Should you need to export instance of an object, use either

```
module.exports = new Foo();
```

or

```
module.exports = new Foo;
```

these two options are equivalent.

If it's required to export the class itself, so that the module consumer can create instances on his own, then class export

```
module.exports = Foo;
```

is the way to go.