# Simple Javascript OOP Confusion

Tags: javascript, oop, object

To create a new empty object in javascript we can write in 2 ways. 
1. With object literal syntax:

```
const obj = {}
```

2.Or with constructor function syntax:

```
const obj = new Object()
```

Today I accidentally typed out `const obj = new Object` saw it also worked, where it should've thrown 
an error because I'd not invoked the constructor function which is done by a set of parenthesis.

I know that the `new` operator with a constructor function does 3 things. 
1. creates a new empty object. 
2. sets the value of `this` to the new object. 
3. return the newly created object from the constructor function.

---

Is the constructor functions invocation is optional? 
So what am I missing?

Comment: The `new` operator is what provides the full context ("Create a new instance of"). Parenthesis can be omitted if you don't need to pass arguments, just like e.g. you're omitting the ending semicolon.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot  @ÁlvaroGonzález

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a special case, for the new operator only, JavaScript simplifies the grammar by allowing the parenthesis to be omitted if there are no arguments in the function call. Here are some examples using the new operator:

```js
o = new Object;  // Optional parenthesis omitted here
d = new Date();
```

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3034952/7616528).

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot 