# What's a better algorithm to remove duplicates from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates, big-o

I have an array of objects that looks something like (rough example):

```
[{id:1, stuff:moreStuff}, {id:6, manyStuff,Stuffing}, {id:4, yayStuff, stuff}, {id:6, manyStuff, Stuffing}]
```

The problem is that in the array, there are several duplicate objects. The current solution I've thought of so far is something along the lines of this:

```
const DuplicateCheck = []
const FinalResult = []

for (let i = 0; i < ArrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
    let isPresent = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < duplicateCheck.length; j++) {
        if (ArrayOfObjects[i].id == duplicateCheck[j]) {
            isPresent = true;
        }
    }
    if (isPresent = false) {
        DuplicateCheck.push(ArrayOfObjects[i].id
        FinalResult.push(ArrayOfObjects[i]
    }
}
```

Now after learning big O, it seems like this is a very inefficient way to go about doing this problem. So my question is, is there a better, more efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: One approach: Sort into array 2, copy back.  If the array is sorted, duplicates appear one after the other so you only need to look at the previous value.  O ( n log n ) sort + O ( n ) copy.    There might be better approaches if you google, like adding to hash table and copying back from that?

Comment: If one were to map the objects to `JSON` strings, create a new `Set` from that, create a new `Array` from the set, then map the now unique elements back to objects, what would be the `O` of that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't get points for closing questions as a dupe. You'd know that if you read the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) page instead of going with your prejudices. Also, you're not the OP @GirkovArpa, so why are you even responding?

Comment: @GirkovArpa: Removing duplicate questions is a community service, earning no reputation points or other rewards.

Comment: Based on the aggressiveness of dupe-finders I'd never have imagined that.

Comment: @GirkovArpa Who was the aggressor here again?

Comment: My last question was attacked by dupe-finders 3 times in the name of "community service."

Comment: @GirkovArpa: the site as a whole is better when there are definitive answers to common questions.  That's why we have duplicate-closing.  Various people spend less or more amounts of effort to check for duplicates, but when they'r found it's a good thing.

Comment: I support duplicate-closing in general but not how it's practiced on this site.  I mentioned my last question.  Also this question is specifically about algorithmic efficiency and Big O notation, yet was recommended to be closed in favor of a question that was not directly about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for your `DuplicateCheck` which gives you `O(1)` access by id:

```
const duplicateCheck = new Set
const finalResult = []

for (const object of arrayOfObjects) {
    if (!duplicateCheck.has(object.id)) {
        duplicateCheck.add(object.id)
        finalResult.push(object)
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `new Set` be `new Set()`? Or are the parentheses optional these days?

Comment: @3limin4t0r Parenthesis for constructor calls [have always been optional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3034941/1048572) :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could keep `usedIds` as object properties and add to the filtered array only if the object has no such property or just add your items in [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) if that's a possibility for you. Set as a data structure can only store non-duplicates.

**Without Set:**

```
const filteredArray = [];
const usedIds = {};

for (const item of array) {
  if (!usedIds[item.id]) {
    usedIds[item.id] = true;
    filteredArray.push(item);
  }
}
```

**With Set:**

```
const filteredArray = [];
const usedIds = new Set();

for (const item of array) {
  if (!usedIds.has(item.id)) {
    usedIds.add(item.id);
    filteredArray.push(item);
  }
}
```

**Runnable example:**

```js
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    stuff: 'stuff',
    moreStuff: 'moreStuff'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    manyStuff: 'manyStuff',
    stuffing: 'stuffing'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    yayStuff: 'yayStuff',
    stuff: 'stuff'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    manyStuff: 'manyStuff',
    stuffing: 'stuffing'
  }
];

const filteredArray = [];
const usedIds = {};

for (const item of array) {
  if (!usedIds[item.id]) {
    usedIds[item.id] = true;
    filteredArray.push(item);
  }
}

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the array and store the `id` in and object (hash table) and then check if exist. Something like:

```
const DuplicateCheck = {}
const FinalResult = []

for (let i = 0; i < ArrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
    let currentId = ArrayOfObjects[i].id

    if (!DuplicateCheck[currentId]) {
        DuplicateCheck[currentId] = 1
        FinalResult.push(ArrayOfObjects[i])
    }
}
```

And you will receive all unique objects in the FinalResult

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to filter out duplicates. Contrary to the [`Set` approach by Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63123378/3982562) this solution leaves the last version of the duplicate, since it overrides the key/value-pair with the same key.

```
const objectsById = new Map(arrayOfObjects.map(object => [object.id, object]));
const finalResult = Array.from(objectsById.values());
```

The code above does need to iterate the collection 2 times. Once using `map` to create key/value-pairs and once when the created array is converted to a `Map`.

When the resulting `objectsById` is created we'll have to iterate over the values to convert them back to array.

In total this means between 2 and 3 iterations over the full collection, which more often then not still a lot faster then solutions using `find`. Since that iterates over the array every time it is called.

You can reduce the amount of iterations by 1 if you omit the `map` call and manually insert the elements in `objectsById`:

```
const objectsById = new Map();
for (const object of arrayOfObjects) {
  objectsById.set(object.id, object);
}
```